# iOS 6.0 Google Maps SDK autocomplete feature

Tags: google-maps, ios6, autocomplete

I investigated this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro?hl=uk
and have some question. I want to use autocomplete feature (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) but in this case i need to kreate 2 different APP KEYs because there are no any methods in SDK to implement this part of API. I tryed link for autocomplete from examples like:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
and tryed use both my iOS and Browser App keys from google APIs console (screencast(dot)com/t/VmxO4EjDB59L) and it's every time return me EQUEST_DENIED. 
Please advice, how i can use amazing autocomplete feature in iOS 6.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, i need use two different keys, but it's no problem because i use one project Id. And importent to activate Places API in console.